# How can I run JEST unit tests that are written by users at runtime in a browser-based editor like Ace Editor, to test JavaScript code the users wrote?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, ace-editor

I teach Javascript at college. I want to write course exams that need to run unit tests on the code that my students wrote.

I need to create exams that will run jest unit tests on the code that my students wrote.
much like [edabit](https://edabit.com/) or [codewars](https://www.codewars.com/) where you have challenges with predefined tests...
At some point the students are required to write their own jest unit tests and run it against their own code like you can do in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).

I'm using **ace editor** for now to allow students to write code in the browser. I need your help with the following:

1. What sort of Jest variations / configurations are needed to write pre-defined unit tests in order to test the students' code in the browser?
2. What is the best way to run code written in a browser based editor? I assume a simple **eval()** is problematic and not secure... I need to run it in the browser so node.js is not an option.
3. How do you support importing/exporting of ES6 modules? Is it true that you need to write your own module bundler to execute in the browser? Is it the only way? Do any of the module bundlers out there support browser-based bundling?

Comment: Did you get an answer to this question? Looking for an answer to similar problem.

Comment: I'm looking for the same thing, so if you got an answer I'd appreciate if you share it with us